# How to implement Parse query properly to get ordered data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have below code to build a query out of two queries.

Issue is result is not sorted by updatedAt.

What could be the issue?

```
let ownerQuery = PFQuery(className: "requests")
ownerQuery.whereKey("owner", equalTo: forUser)
ownerQuery.whereKey("stage", equalTo: "initiated")

let requestQuery = PFQuery(className: "requests")
requestQuery.whereKey("requested_by", equalTo: requestedBy)
requestQuery.whereKey("stage", equalTo: "accepted")

// fetch all request of current user as requestor or lender/seller
let query = PFQuery.orQuery(withSubqueries: [ownerQuery, requestQuery])

query.includeKey("requested_by")
query.includeKey("owner")
query.order(byDescending: "updatedAt")
```

Comment: Just guessing... maybe you need to include the sort key (`updatedAt`) in the result set by means of `includeKey` in order to make sorting work...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue turned out to be code where i was processing the retrieved data. Parse returned sorted result.

I have below code where ordering gets affected. it seems to be because of getDetails() returning in async.

So i have added array sort before returning. I retrieve 20 rows at a time so sorting every array should not be costly i guess.

I had also posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4717#issuecomment-381327245). Awaiting confirmation.

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (results, error) in
            if error == nil {
                for result in results! {

                    group.enter()

                    let stage = result["stage"] as! String
                    let requestedBy = result["requested_by"] as! PFUser

                    DBHelper.getDetails(result["requested_id"] as! String, callbackFunction: { (requestedItem) in
                        let owner = result["owner"] as! PFUser
                        let request =  Request()

                        request.requestId = result.objectId
                        request.item = requestedItem

                        request.owner = owner
                       request.lastUpdatedDate = result.updatedAt
                        requestsFound.append(request)

                        group.leave()
                    }) 
                } 
                group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background), execute: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        requestsFound.sort {(request1:Request, request2:Request) -> Bool in
                            request1.lastUpdatedDate! < request2.lastUpdatedDate!
                        }
                        callbackFunction(requestsFound,nil) 
                    }  
                })

            }  else {
                // encountered error from Parse
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    callbackFunction(requestsFound,error! as NSError) // to represent error at backend server

                }

            } 


            } //end of findObjectsInBackground
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
ownerQuery.order(byAscending: "updatedAt")
```

Comment: Fails with NSException atPFParameterAssert(subquery.state.sortKeys.count == 0, @"OR queries do not support sub queries with order");  i have found a work around. Posting separately.